# Change screen saver auto-lock time based on current wifi network

Tags: security, geolocation, screen-lock

I would like to make mac require a password after being asleep for 30 seconds when it is not on my home wifi network, but only require a password after 4 hours when its on my home network. I have wanted this for years but have never figured out how to do it. Is it possible?

Comment: You could make your Mac require a password after X seconds of screen saver or when display is turned off in *System Settings > Lock Screen*. The option is called "Require password after screen saver begins or display is turned off", you'll have a popup menu to open asking for the "X" seconds. I guess you could use [ControlPlane](https://www.controlplaneapp.com/) for the rest of it although I'm unsure whether it would work.